# How to run multiple spiders from Python Script at once?

Tags: python, scrapy

i have created 4 spiders i want more than 1 spiders to run when i run the script
so far i have tried this but no help

i have these 4 spiders

```
def BestBuyIphoneA(domain):
    dispatcher.connect(stop_reactor, signal=signals.spider_closed)
    spider = BestBuy(domain=domain)
    settings = get_project_settings()
    settings.overrides['ITEM_PIPELINES'] = {'__main__.MyPipeline': 1}
    crawler = Crawler(settings)
    crawler.signals.connect(spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
    crawler.configure()
    crawler.crawl(spider)
    crawler.start()

def BestBuyLappyA(domain):
    dispatcher.connect(stop_reactor, signal=signals.spider_closed)
    spider = BestBuyLappy(domain=domain)
    settings = get_project_settings()
    settings.overrides['ITEM_PIPELINES'] = {'__main__.MyPipeline': 1}
    crawler2 = Crawler(settings)
    crawler2.signals.connect(spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
    crawler2.configure()
    crawler2.crawl(spider)
    crawler2.start()

def ShopBotLappyB(domain):
    dispatcher.connect(stop_reactor, signal=signals.spider_closed)
    spider = ShopBotLappy(domain=domain)
    settings = get_project_settings()
    settings.overrides['ITEM_PIPELINES'] = {'__main__.MyPipeline': 1}
    crawler3 = Crawler(settings)
    crawler3.signals.connect(spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
    crawler3.configure()
    crawler3.crawl(spider)
    crawler3.start()

def ShopBotIphoneB(domain):
    dispatcher.connect(stop_reactor, signal=signals.spider_closed)
    spider = ShopBot(domain=domain)
    settings = get_project_settings()
    settings.overrides['ITEM_PIPELINES'] = {'__main__.MyPipeline': 1}
    crawler4 = Crawler(settings)
    crawler4.signals.connect(spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
    crawler4.configure()
    crawler4.crawl(spider)
    crawler4.start()
```

i need to run all of them on 1 single command so im doing this...

```
BestBuyIphoneA("")
ShopBotIphoneB("")
BestBuyLappyA("")
ShopBotLappyB("")
reactor.run()
```

what is the correct way to do this????